# Custom Messages for Ignition Transport

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'd like to use Ignition Transport in a new projects, and I want to be able to have custom messages. I understand ignition transport "uses protobuf". Should I generate the C++ classes and then register them with ignition transport somehow? What is the process for using custom messages types with ignition transport?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17131/custom-messages-for-ignition-transport/) by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 768 on 2017-08-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I created a new example and tutorial motivated by this question. Check it out [here](https://bitbucket.org/ignitionrobotics/ign-transport/pull-requests/219).

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2017-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1